# Prevent duplication in a PHP filter

Tags: php, sql, database, filter

So I have an another problem with my filtering system. I am getting my filtered results when I choose an option from the first dropdown I have. But I also get below the filtered results a block where I see my options from the second dropdown (duplicated) and below that I have again ALL of my results I have in the database. How can I prevent this?

[image: This is my Filter now]

Here is my index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // Live anzeigen der 2. Ebene + 1 Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#category').on('change', function(){
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'category_id='+categoryID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#subcategory').html(html);
            $('#partner').html(html);
            $('#subcategory').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#subcategory').html('<option value="">Zuerst Überkategorie auswählen!</option>');
      }
    }); 

    // Live Anzeigen der 3. Ebene + 2. Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#subcategory').on('change', function(){
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'subcategory_id='+subcategoryID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#subcategory2').html(html);
            $('#partner').html(html);
            $('#subcategory2').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#subcategory2').html('<option value="">Zuerst Unterkategorie auswählen! 
    </option>');
      }
    });

    // Live anzeigen der 3. Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#subcategory2').on('change', function(){
      var subcategory2ID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategory2ID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'subcategory2_id='+subcategory2ID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#partner').html(html);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#partner').html('<h1>Zuerst Unterkategorie auswählen!</h1>');
      }
    });
  });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php

  // Include connection.php
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';

  // Fetch all the category data
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY category_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

?>

<!-- Category dropdown -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    

      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="col">
          <select id="category" name="category" class="dropdown">

            <?php

              if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
                  echo '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';

                }
              } else {
                echo '<option value="">Nicht verfügbar!</option>';
              }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Subcategory dropdown -->
          <select id="subcategory" name="subcategory" class="dropdown" disabled>
            <option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <!-- 2nd subcategory dropdown -->
          <select id="subcategory2" name="subcategory2" class="dropdown" disabled>
            <option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
      </form>

    
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Show all results -->
  <div id="all_results">
      <? /*
      $query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
      $result = $connect->query($query);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0){
      } */
      ?>
  </div>



<!-- Partner results -->
<div id="partner">
  <?php

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
        ?>
        <div>
          <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
          <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
          <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
        </div>
        <?php 
      }
    } else {
      echo '<p>Nichts gefunden!<p>';
    }
   ?>
</div>


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is my ajaxdata.php:

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconfig.php';

//Dropdown No. 1
if(!empty($_POST['category_id']))
{

  // Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 1. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 
ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
    ?>        
      <div class="div_results">
        <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
        <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
        <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
  }

  // Anzeigen der Kategorien der 2. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY subcategory_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    echo '<option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>';

    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['subcategory_id'].'">'.$row['subcategory_name'].'</option>';
    }
  } 

  // Anzeigen aller Ergebnisse
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM partner WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

  if($_POST["category_id"] != "Alle")
  {
    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
    ?>        
      <div class="div_results">
        <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
        <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
        <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
  }   
  else {
    echo '<option value="">Nothing found!</option>';
  }
}

// Dropdown No. 2
elseif(!empty($_POST['subcategory_id']))
{

  // Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 2. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE subcategory_id = ".$_POST['subcategory_id']." AND 
status = 1 ORDER BY  partner_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
    ?>
    
      <div>
        <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
        <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
        <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
  }

  // Anzeigen der Kategorien der 3. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories2 WHERE subcategory_id = ".$_POST['subcategory_id']." 
AND status = 1 ORDER BY subcategory2_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    echo '<option value="">Untekategorie auswählen!</option>';

    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
      echo '<option 
value="'.$row['subcategory2_id'].'">'.$row['subcategory2_name'].'</option>';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<option value="">Nichts gefunden!</option>';
  }
}


// Dropdown No. 3
elseif(!empty($_POST['subcategory2_id'])){

// Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 3. Ebene (Letzte Ebene)
$query  = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE subcategory2_id = ".$_POST['subcategory2_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);

if($result->num_rows > 0){

  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    ?>
    <div>
      <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
      <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
      <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
} else {
  echo 'Nothing found!';
}
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong so this shows everything when I am filtering

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` makes no sense - you don't need to load jQuery twice. (This isn't the source of the problem in your question, but it's certainly unnecessary and inefficient, and occasionally it can actually cause problems). Just keep one of those lines, not both of them.

Comment: But the one is local, so when I want to write something by myself or not?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point. They are both copies of the same file. You only need one of them. it doesn't matter if it's on your local server or not, your web page doesn't care where it comes from, as long as it can load it successfully. Once its loaded, it's origin is irrelevant, it behaves the same.

Comment: Anyway - I edited your post to add proper indentation and spacing to your ajaxdata.php, so we can see the flow of the code more easily. It was hard to read before. Once I did that, it is very clear that inside the `if(!empty($_POST['category_id']))` area you are running two versions of the `SELECT * FROM partner...` query, and outputting the results from both. The first version is filtered, but the second version isn't. I have no idea why you're doing that. It doesn't appear to make any sense, but it's very obvious that this is the source of the issue.

Comment: So how can I fix it best?

Comment: Ok so I fixed the double filtering. I changed the place from the code for showing all results to elseif in the first version of `SELECT * FROM partner ... ` but the code for changing the second dropdown still prints a second html under the filtered results.

Comment: Well of course it does. That's exactly what you told it to do. You're just outputting one big stream of HTML. Then you've written `$('#subcategory').html(html);
            $('#partner').html(html);` which attempts to put the same single stream of HTML into both parts of your page! The first command likely doesn't entirely work correctly because you're trying to put divs inside a select. And the second one prints everything that was output by the PHP - it has no way of telling which bit you wanted to print there, and which bit was intended for the dropdown. You gave it no way to differentiate

Comment: You either need to a) return a JSON object from the PHP, with two properties - one property containing the HTML for the search result, and one containing the HTML for the dropdown. Then the Javascript can easily read the correct bit into each part of your page separately. Or b) make two AJAX calls, one to return the search result and one to return the categories. a) is a tiny bit more complex, but is also likely to be a lot more efficient than b). It's up to you really. But certainly, returning everything in one big lump is no good because the Javascript can't easily tell which bit is which.

Comment: You know how to make this with ajax easily?

Comment: You're already using AJAX. And you already know how to make different parts of your ajaxdata.php respond to different AJAX requests (because your existing code already does that - you already have 3 different AJAX calls which execute different parts of ajaxdata.php, depending on different POST values). So you already know that technique, if you think about it. P.S. Both my suggestions involve AJAX, but in different ways. I assumed you're talking about option b - is that correct?

Comment: No I don't understand option b). I'm still a very low level

Comment: Well, programming is all about re-using patterns and practices you've already learned, and applying them to a new situation where you need to do a similar task. What I'm saying is, option b means you have to make 2 separate ajax requests instead of 1 - one to fetch the results, and one to fetch the dropdown options. If you look at the code you've got now, which makes separate ajax requests when the different dropdowns are changed, and passes a different POST value to make PHP decide which `if` statement to enter, you'd be using a similar technique if you split it up into more ajax requests.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense, then, do you understand option a) any better?

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. Do I have to change IDs or something? ...

Comment: what IDs? I've no idea what you mean. ID doesn't seem to be related to the problem.

Comment: And I've no idea what precisely you tried, or what "doesn't work" exactly means. I can't fix a problem if you aren't specific about it.

Comment: So i sliced the first ajax function in 2 functions. in the one function there is only `$('#subcategory').html(html);` as result if the function is successful. I the other AJAX function I have the other 3 "results". And now everything works same. I know I still have to change something but I don't know what.

Comment: Sorry that's still not clear enough for me to understand. Real code is worth the same as 1000 words which attempt to describe that code - always remember that. If we could describe functionality accurately in regular human language, we wouldn't need programming languages! Anyway, option a) is far more efficient, as I already mentioned. I've written an answer below which should help you understand what to do, and also gives an example which I think will work (albeit I'm unable to test it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem (returning an unfiltered set of results as well as the filtered set), it's simply that you are running two versions of the `SELECT * FROM partner...` query, and outputting the results from both. The first version is filtered, but the second version isn't. You just need to remove the second version - it's not clear why that's there to begin with.

For the second problem (outputting the dropdown options after the results), the issue is that you're just outputting one big stream of HTML. Then you've written `$('#subcategory').html(html); $('#partner').html(html);` which attempts to put the same single stream of HTML into both parts of your page! The first command likely doesn't entirely work correctly because you're trying to put divs inside a select. And the second one prints everything that was output by the PHP - it has no way of telling which bit you wanted to print there, and which bit was intended for the dropdown. You gave it no way to differentiate.

It would make more sense to return a JSON object from the PHP, with two properties - one property containing the HTML for the search result, and one containing the HTML for the dropdown. Then the Javascript can easily read the correct bit into each part of your page separately.

Something like this should work I think (although obviously it's not easy for me to test it):

JavaScript:

```
    $('#category').on('change', function(){
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'category_id='+categoryID,
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(response){
            $('#subcategory').html(response.subcategories);
            $('#partner').html(response.results);
            $('#subcategory').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#subcategory').html('<option value="">Zuerst Überkategorie auswählen!</option>');
      }
    });
```

PHP:

```
//Dropdown No. 1
if(!empty($_POST['category_id']))
{

  // Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 1. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 
ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);
  $resultHTML = "";

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
      $resultHTML .=        
      '<div class="div_results">
        <h1>'.$row['partner_name'].'</h1><br>
        <img src="'.$row['partner_logo'].'"><br>
        <a href="'.$row['partner_link'].'">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
      </div>';
    }
  }

  // Anzeigen der Kategorien der 2. Ebene
  $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY subcategory_name ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);
  $subCategoryHTML = "";

  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    $subCategoryHTML .= '<option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>';

    while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC())
    {
      $subCategoryHTML .= '<option value="'.$row['subcategory_id'].'">'.$row['subcategory_name'].'</option>';
    }
  }

  $returnData = array("results" => $resultHTML, "subcategories" => $subCategoryHTML);
  echo json_encode($returnData);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223158/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-prevent-duplication-in-a-php-filter).